# jquery ajax loading gif while waiting for ajax response

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

Been having his problem I can't seem to work out, Im trying to post a url to this page for PHP processing (which works), but it can take up to 10 seconds to respond, so I been trying to have a loading gif show while its waiting and it does not seen to go in order.
Here is what I got:

```
$("#r_link_e").html('<img src="<?php echo base_url()?>images/ajax-loader.gif"  />');

        if($("#r_link").val() != ''){

            //Check             
                $.ajax({
                    url: "<?php echo base_url()?>home/check_url/"+$("#r_link").val(),
                    type: 'GET',
                    async: false,
                    cache: false,
                    timeout: 30000,
                    success: function(data) {
                        alert(data);
                    }
            });
```

What happens on the page:

- Url submits
- page freezes
- alert of response
- Loading gif shows

Thank you for any help :)

Comment: Remove `async: false,` or set it as `true`.

Comment: Async should ALWAYS be true. There's no purpose on using ajax otherwise.

Comment: ^^ that's a huge overgeneralization

Comment: Yes but if I set async to true, it will not wait for a response from the ajax call

Comment: Why are you waiting? When dealing with these types of techniques, I find it's usually because the coder does not have a good grasp of callback handlers and thus wish to make a call wait so it runs concurrently in a synchronous style. This is not how (primarily) AJAX-style programming is meant to work, you have to learn closures and callback handling to use it correctly.

Comment: because its part of a validation, I need to check the URL using PHP script and then if it is OK, then can submit the form. Thinking some how use a timer function to check.

Comment: No, the success (callback) handler should do the validation and if valid, *submit the form within the handler*.

Answer (score 1):

If you set `async: false`, you're telling the browser to *synchronize* to that function's call responding, meaning it is going to *wait*. Remove or set to `true` and it will run *asynchronously*, e.g., will not freeze the browser waiting for it to finish.

Comment: But it does not wait for the ajax call, it goes onto other function after it, should I use something like a timer to check?

Comment: This and your last comment below the question seem to say different things.

Comment: See if you can figure out what I'm trying to do with this demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/GVJ7b/2/ Note, you should have you JS console open.